# Rewrite many URL parameters to more "readable" format

Tags: url-rewriting, friendly-url, optional-parameters

**Context:** An events system with many (optional) search parameters. Whilst this is partly a UX question, I feel this still belongs on SO.

A plain URL might look like:

```
example.com/events?date=X-Y-Z&type=race&location=Lapland
```

And the proposed 'more readable' format:

```
example.com/events/location:lapland|type:race|date:X-Y-Z
```

Would you argue that the latter is no more readable than the former? Or that the trade-off for having 'reinvented' the query syntax isn't worth it? Or perhaps another syntax suggestion?

**NB:** I've strayed from the typical rewrite `events/{location}/{type}/{date}`, since these are all optional query filters, and there'd be no discernible way to map values to their associated parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just how is using : and | over = and & any improvement? The gain of "readable" URLs as emitted by certain CMSes (like Wordpress) is that they *do not* contain any variable names, and work with per-post tags instead, e.g. `example.com/tags/lapland`, `example.com/tags/race/`, `example.com/2011/12/13/`, and though I have not remembered any syntax for ANDing tags, the most meaningful would be a space, as in `example.com/tags/lapland race`. As that will be x-www-urlencoded with a plus as `example.com/tags/lapland+race` (some browsers will display a space, some the urlencoded form) you get a good mnemonic (x+y.. x and y, sort of).

Comment: `Just how is using : and | over = and & any improvement?` After having written out my thoughts & reflected, I agree. Coincidentally, this is on a WordPress build, but `location`, `race` etc. are their own taxonomy - hence the need for a 'signifier'; something to say 'this value is a location, this value is a type'...